# Tooltip Wrap in Nebular Framework

Tags: angular, nebular

I am working in the Akveo Nebular framework using the ngxAdmin core theme using tooltips as hints on complicated settings. I am needing the tooltip to wrap, however, using the traditional CSS methods are not working correctly.

The tooltip format I am using for my tooltip is

```
<i nbTooltip="Information here" class="ic-info"></i>
```

I have tried adding a container around the i and have also tried adding a container around the entire group (including the label and i).

I have tried several inline styles as well, but cannot get them to apply to the nbTooltip.

I have also attempted to add   `tooltip-max-width: 250px,` to the theme.scss and it seems to have no affect.

Comment: Tooltip container has `max-width` set to `16rem` by default. I've created a sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-tooltip-wrap?file=src/app/app.component.html) with long tooltip text and it wraps as expected. If something is missing you can fork and modify it to illustrate your case.

Comment: Out of the provided info looks like something is wrong with the setup.
The first thing to check is styles applied to `nb-tooltip` element.
Make tooltip appear then find `nb-tooltip` element in dev tools elements panel and look for its styles. You should see something like this:
https://i.imgur.com/t37ViQw.jpg.
Probably there are some styles which override `max-width`.
If `nb-tooltip` has no styles as on the picture above there is definitely some issue with the theme set up. Then please post contents of your `theme.scss` file and we'll try to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```js
::ng-deep .multiline-tooltip {
    white-space: pre-line !important;
}
```

```html
<nb-icon nbTooltipClass="multiline-tooltip" icon="alert-info"
               nbTooltip="Text1 &#13;&#10; Text2"></nb-icon>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There's the problem also in nebular 5.0.

My current workaround:

Not a real solution but i made my own tooltip using like this.
adjust margin-top for distance from item.

**>component.html**

```
<div class="myTooltip">
    <span class="myTooltipText"> <!--Tooltip content --> </span>
    ...
</div>
```

**>component.scss**

```
.myTooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.myTooltip .myTooltipText {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 400px;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0 15px;
  background: #b2d3e4;
  color: #00639e;
  text-align: justify;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: -70px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: visible;
  min-height: 54px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-flex;
  transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
}

.myTooltip .myTooltipText::after {
  content: " ";
  left: 10%;
  bottom: -10px;
  overflow: visible;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  color: #00639e;
  z-index: 99999;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #b2d3e4 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.myTooltip:hover .myTooltipText {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```